# Indicator-+ 100% CPU 100%Memory right after login

Tags: login, indicator, freeze

When booting my Ubuntu 16.10, everything is fine till the login window. When I enter my login and password, the session starts, but freezes within seconds.
When opening a terminal and typing "top" (before the freeze...), I can see the a process called Indicator+- goes up to 100% CPU and Memory.
If I kill that process, another one starts after a few seconds, with the same 100%.
Is there a way to get this Indicator-+ to behave??
Thanks for reading. Philippe.

Comment: You may want to report this as a bug, if you can figure out what package contains the executable. Is `indicator-+` really the program name? (try `top -c`)

Comment: In the top listing, it is posted as "indicator-+". I cannot run top -c anymore to verify if it gives another name, since I solved the problem by copying my home folder (with a slight change in name), creating a new one under my name, and adding back the only files I needed from the "old" one. Now, everything looks good. :-)

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if this program should be on your system at all. On mine, `apt-file search indicator-+` doesn't show up anything. On yours? What does `which indicator-+` tell you? Does it restart with a different process ID, and if it does, what is its parent process? Can you kill that?

Comment: "which indicator-+" does not give anything on my system either, at least now after my Home folder clean-up. However, you can find another report of it in top listing here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2339788&p=13556181#post13556181 In that case though, it was not eating all resources and was no culprit.

Comment: No, there the `+` is only an indication that the command has been abbreviated. That is why I asked for `top -c`. The program is not really called `indicator-+` but rather `indicator-weather` or whatever. No wonder I couldn't find it with `apt-file` :-).

Comment: Yes, of course! I did not think of that! Hm.... In that case, the only two extra indicators that I think were used were TeamViewer and Dropbox. But I guess I am not the only one using them. I did not set TeamViewer yet after the cleanup. I'll keep that in mind when I do, in case the problem reappears. Thanks for the advice.